# Java Mutex Association with Condition Variable

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, pthreads, condition-variable

Each condition variable in Java (wait() notify()) is associated with a single mutex (synchronized).

I was said than (in Java), each mutex is also associated with a single condition variable, and that is a less efficient implementation than pthreads' cond variables and mutexes for instance. I cannot understand this one however. What does that mean? How is Java different than C/C++ pthreads on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inability to associate more than one condition variable with a single mutex is limiting.  For example, suppose you want to implement a multi-producer, multi-consumer blocking queue (e.g., `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue`).

There has to be only one mutex:  It won't work to have one mutex for producers and a different one for consumers.  But using Java's `synchronized` mechanism, that means there can only be one condition variable too.  That means, a consumer that makes the queue become "not-full" must signal the same condition that is signalled by a producer that makes the queue become "not-empty".  And *that* means, that producers and consumers must `notifyAll()`, because otherwise there is no guarantee that the one thread that is awakened by a producer won't be another producer or, that the one thread awakened by a consumer won't be another consumer.

In a pthreads-based implementation, the queue can have one mutex, and one condition variable for producers to wait on, and a different condition variable for consumers to wait on.

---

Fortunately, the Java standard library provides an alternative way of locking:  The `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` interface defines a mutex that can give out any number of associated `Condition` objects.